# Use IPTables to force TCP packets over router

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables

To test a TCP-stack program, I need to get the TCP packets via the router. When I try to connect to my server program via the router, the OS does not hit the router as the destination IP is the same as the source IP.

Can I make a temporary rule to tell the Linux stack to use a specific adapter (`wlan0`) and a specific router address for outgoing TCP packets with a specific target port (`5101`)?

Comment: Linux will use `wlan0` if that is the route for the IP. Does it need to be port 5101, or can all traffic be temporarily routed through the router? Why don't you try `man ip-route`?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: I checked with wireshark, and there is definitively no packet going over `wlan0` when accessing the computer's own IP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your problem, but it seems to me (*if* I have understood it right), that a simpler oslution is to have your program listen on loopback (127.0.0.1), and then send your packets to loopback (with the appropriate port, of course).

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as I am testing a self-written TCP/IP stack and I need to receive the packet via the router on the specified adapter.